# select 1st 5 character, in string array in C#

Tags: c#

i want to select 1st 5 character from list of string array,

```
List<string> strDetailIDList = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   strDetailIDList.Add(row.ToString());
}              
str=strDetailIDList.ToArray();
```

now str containing list like

```
FOCMM001
FOCMM002
FOCMM003
FOCMM004
FOCMM005
FOCMM006
FOCSM013
FOCSM014
FOCSM015
FOCSM016
FOCSM017
FOCSM018
FOCSM019
SC1LN001
SC1LN002
SC1LN003
SC1LN004
SC1LN005
SC1LN006
```

from this list i want to select 1st 5 character and count FOCMM-6,FOCSM-6,SC!LN-6. Plz suggest some idea.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var counts = list.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 5))
                 .Select(g => new { Prefix = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
foreach (var value in counts)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", value.Prefix, value.Count);
}
```

Comment: i want to display it in label

Comment: @chitra: Well I don't have time to change the answer now - you should have included that information in the question... and more detail about it. One label? Several labels? Given the information so far, which bit of putting it in a label is giving you problems? This sounds like a separate question.

Comment: sir, it giving total number of records, i want to display each item in separate label as i mention above

Comment: @chitra: As I said, you should ask this as a separate question - if you *really* can't work out how to change my loop which uses `Console.WriteLine` into a loop which adds labels...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display in label, then simply change ConsoleWriteLine with:

```
foreach (var value in counts)
{
    label1.Text +=  string.Format(("{0} - {1}\r\n", value.Prefix, value.Count));
}
```

if you only want to show in one line remove "\r\n" from the upper line of code

Comment: sir, it giving total number of records, i want to display each item in separate label as i mention above

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe this can help you. It only works if the list is ordered, as it seems to be by the provided sample.

```
int Count = 0;
List<String> Result = new List<String>();
String LastString= "";
for(int loop=0;loop<strDetailIDList.Count; loop++)
{
    if(LastString!=strDetailIDList[loop].Substring(5))
    {
        if(LastString!="") 
        {
             Result.Add(LastString+"-"+Count);
        }
        LastString=strDetailIDList[loop].Substring(5);
        Count = 1;
    }
    else Count++;
}
```

Now the "Result" list have the text you need to display on your labels.

Comment: You're assuming the strings come in order. They happen to in the sample, but I don't see any indication that that's necessarily the case. (It's also really odd to see local variables in Pascal case.)

Comment: Since they are comming from a table, you can order them on retrieval (order by). At anycase, this code provides a sample solution to the problem, as it is the intention. The actual handling of the complete solution will be decided by the programmer, since he/she is the only one that knows all the parameters of the problem.

Comment: Yes, you *can* order them - but you hadn't even mentioned that in your answer. You've added an extra requirement unnecessarily, and still ended up with more complicated code.

Comment: The person that asks a question, asked for ideas. This is mine. The code is hardly complicated and it is intended to show another approach. The sample provided shows **clearly** the values are sorted. I am not fond of linq, and my approach does not require it.

Comment: The sample data happens to be ordered, but that's absolutely no indication that it will be in all cases. Your approach *does* require it, as if you have XXXXX01YYYYY02XXXXX03 your approach will give *three* groups instead of two. Therefore even if you believe the data *will* be sorted in all cases - or at least grouped together - you should state that in your answer. (Why don't you like LINQ, by the way? It makes life *much* simpler in so many situations.) Also, any reason for not using `foreach`? There's no need to use list indexes here... generally `foreach` is preferred for readability.

Comment: You are right, that I should state the requirement in my suggestion. I edited my answer to include the requirement. Thank you.